# Make UIView stay on screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I make a UIView that is movable by the user on the screen, it is a round rectangle that is 40x40, and the screen that it is on has a nav bar at the top and right now it can be moved under the nav bar, and then it is gone and can't come back.

Is there a way to make it so that it can't be moved off the screen?

I make it moveable like this:

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;

- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x, recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

}
```

So my question is how can I make it so it can be moved off the screen.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I suggest to add UISwipeGestureRecognizer. By swipe gesture you can move off the screen your UIView (with animation).

Comment: @stosha I want to keep it on the screen, not swipe it off?

Comment: You are controlling it, validate the new coordinates before applying them.